# Struggling with iOS memory management with ARC

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments

I watched the 2012 WWDC session 242 video on using Instruments to run down memory issues and thought I would build a very simple app to try out what I had learned.

My app uses a storyboard with two viewControllers in it.  The first viewController displays a UILabel and a UIButton.  When you press the button the second viewController is loaded, and it too displays a UILabel and a UIButton that when pressed, removes the second viewController so that the first one is displayed again.  In instruments I expected to see some memory allocated as the second viewController is added, and then that memory to deallocate so that I would be back to the original amount of memory used.  That is in fact how the Apple demo works in the WWDC video.

What I see instead, as I take snapshots each time I press the dismiss button and return to viewController one, is that memory usage continues to creep upwards by a very small amount.  It is never zero...it always goes up.

It only increases by around 500-700 bytes each time, which I realize is a very small amount, but I want to understand why it increases at all.

The only code added to my first viewController is a single method to add the second view controller which is named VC2 in the storyboard.

```
- (IBAction)addVC2:(id)sender
{
    ViewController2 *template = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];

    [template willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:template];
    [self.view addSubview:template.view];
    [template didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Similarly, the second viewController (VC2) only has a single method added that dismisses/removes it:

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

At one point I added dealloc to VC2 to ensure that it was being called and it was.

I have Instruments Allocation setup like this:

[image]

I can't understand why the memory usage creeps up over and over.  Something is being retained each time I add and remove the second view controller, but I am at a loss to find it.